# Using require_once() in functions.php ONLY when WooCommerce plugin is activated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Genesis Framework/WordPress. For theme development, I'm keeping my functions organized by fragmenting similar functions in my theme's /lib/ folder as includes and then using require_once() to include those functions in the appropriate order in functions.php. I'm aware of the performance considerations for this approach for highly dynamic sites and want to note this is for prod and staging only.

I have a collection of Woocommerce functions that I only want loaded when the WooCommerce plugin is activated. Below you can see the conditional statement that I've tried to construct in functions.php that would force wordpress to load this only when the plugin is activate. I'm admittedly new to PHP development and am having trouble discerning whether this is a method issue, syntax issue or both:

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_woocommerce_activated' ) ) {
function is_woocommerce_activated() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) { 
        require_once( CHILD_DIR . '/lib/cg-woocommerce.php' );}
    else return; }
    }
```

The stylesheets that I have enqueued in my woocommerce.php functions include are still being output in WP_head, which I'm assuming means that the conditional isn't working. Any ideas here or direction on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you output the results of your various calls to ensure they output what you think they will?

Comment: Yes. Everything outputs correctly without the conditionals. WP Head scripts output in the right order, functions all fire correctly, even custom theme options work like a charm  The conditional was intended to be a final step so that I don't have to comment out stuff for every new iteration.

Comment: Also should add that everything still outputs correctly WITH the conditional statement, too. Which is the problem. So it's not a matter of the code I provided breaking functionality...it's a matter of it continuing to load that functions include even when woocommerce isn't activated.